# Unable to execute the android project in MAC with real device (5s)

Tags: appium

I am working as a mobile automation tester for web applications in Android and iOS device. I have recently started the mobile automation using selenium webdriver and Appium for our web applications. we have created the automation project successfully for android device. Now we want use the same project for IOS device and am using iPhone 5s for that.

I have configure Eclipse, Appium and imported our project successfully in MAC. Am able to launcher the safari browser in 5s but unable to execute the project. Can any one please help me how to execute the existing project in mac.

Is my approach on executing the existing android project on MAC using Real device correct or not?

1. I had setup Appium successfully.
2. Able to launch safari browser successfully through Xcode on Real device.
3. While executing the Project through eclipse showing below error.

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource. (Original error: Invalid timeout 'page load') (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: What is your selenium version?  Also can you please put code which you have written to connect with device and execute driver? Put code in your question please.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone(); capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"ios"); capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Device Name"); capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "8.3"); capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/SafariLauncher.app"); capabilities.setCapability("udid","xxxxxxx"); driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);driver.quit();

Comment: I observed new issue.          org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not implemented in this context, try switching into or out of a web view (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: '37l4247f26-21.ssltuiodc.local', ip: '10.174.18.32', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.4', java.version: '1.8.0_45'

Answer (score 0):

@suresh As @Helping Hands mentioned please input the code. The error is pretty clear that it's an unsupported command, so might be you have used methods specific to Android while automating for Android application and are trying to use the same on iOS, which will not work.

Comment: Issue is resolved, as i mentioned in above comments and am facing new error. And there are no specific android method in the project, only the capabilities are changed as we are running in IOS device and other scripting part remains the same as it below to web application. And the Project executing perfectly on Android and desktop browsers but am facing issues in IOS browsers. Can you please suggest me anything.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not implemented in this context, try switching into or out of a web view (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: '37l4247f26-21.ssltuiodc.local', ip: '10.174.18.32', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.4', java.version: '1.8.0_45'